# Negative margin value hides element

Tags: css, layout, scroll, margins

Im trying to make a carousel with arrows. for the arrows to be in the right position and look pretty, im using a negative margin (margin: -Npx).
This causes the arrow to be hidden inside the carousel.
ive trying applying z-index: 9999.
overflow-x of carousel cannot be visible (per design)

[image]

```
const CarouselWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  & > * {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
`;

const ArrowsContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
`;

const ArrowWrapper = styled.div`
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: ${rem(8)};
  pointer-events: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 6.2px -4.95px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
    0px 0px 10.2px 0.55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  visibility: ${({ show }) => (show ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
  &:first-child {
    margin-left: ${rem(-20)};
  }
`;

const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;

    <CarouselContainer>
      <CarouselWrapper ref={ref}>{children}</CarouselWrapper>
      {showArrows && (
        <ArrowsContainer>
          <ArrowWrapper
            show={scrollPosition !== 0}
            onClick={() => scrollToNext(ref.current, -1)}
          >
            <ChevronLeft style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
          </ArrowWrapper>
          <ArrowWrapper
            show={scrollPosition !== maxScrollValue}
            onClick={() => scrollToNext(ref.current)}
          >
            <ChevronRight style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
          </ArrowWrapper>
        </ArrowsContainer>
      )}
    </CarouselContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the

```
`&:first-child {
  margin-left: ${rem(-20)};
 }`
```

has an effect on both the left and the right arrows as you are targeting in both cases the  `<ChevronLeft />` and the `<ChevronRight />` with the `&:first-child` selector. You can remove this from the `ArrowWrapper` styled component and add the margin in the style tag inside the `<ChevronLeft />` and the `<ChevronRight />`

Comment: I agree that this might affect both arrows but this solution still won’t solve the problem here. The carousel container cuts the left arrow and shows only half

Comment: @ConiWright can you create a sandbox so it will be easier to give you a solution? When I tried to replicate your code in a sandbox when i remove the 'margin-left: ${rem(-20)};' puts the left arrow inside the carousel container correct without cutting it